# Pokemon logo (Cubeon) showing on my boot screen

Tags: applications, boot, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g, pokemon-go

I recently installed "Pokemon Go" game in my Redmi Note 4G. The game is working fine. But I noticed something peculiar in my booting screen. It shows up just after the MIUI logo. I took a photo and did a little research and came to know that the logo is of Cubeon, a Pokemon character. I don't know why this is happening. Is there any security issues? How did the app get access to my boot menu?

[image: Pokemon Character]

Comment: Innograpica seems to be an artist that creates boot animations (and other art). Did you install a custom theme too?

Comment: Where did you get the app, there is a malware version going around

Comment: @user1871 I doubt malware would just mess with the boot animation. Hell, I doubt malware would try to leave a trail at all- it doesn't want to get caught!

Comment: Not all malware is for evil some just like to be annoying

Comment: Possible device compromise—there are quite a few fake versions of Pokémon GO out there. You'd probably want to factory reset the device and reflash the OS. In the future, make sure the developer is listed as **Niantic Inc.** and that the number of downloads is very large (at least 10M as of this writing). The real app can be downloaded from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en; the package name is **`com.nianticlabs.pokemongo`**.

Answer (score 2):

It's not from Niantic, it is the silhouette of the MIUI character head.

[image]

It's possible comes with a MIUI theme what you downloaded and applied.

Answer (score 0):

That appears when you install custom themes like in iOS 9 theme (afterglow or retouched I'm not sure), as the theme engine includes options for a theme to change the boot screen.